# Angular 6: Update NG Style with function

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ng-style

I'm here today because I'm wondering something about the NG Style with Angular (**my version being the 6**). How can i **update [ngStyle]** when **I use a function** to return a value.

**As always, here is a simplified example of my problem:**

I generate div from an array of objects.
For each section, **there are two div**: one on the left and one on the right.

**The size of the left div changes depending on the content**, so it can do both 50px and 125px.

**I want the right div to fit the size of the one on his left**, always half that size (2 in getLeftDivHeight).
Obviously, this will be done in each section (Container).

**How can I make the ngStyle update when the div's height to the left changes** (due to resizing, adding content, or page display time)? )

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<section class = "Container" *ngFor="let oneContent of allContent">

<div id = "{{oneContent.id}}" style="float: left">
<p> {{oneContent.Content}} </ p>
</div>

<div style="float: right" [ngStyle]="height: getLeftDivHeight(oneContent.id, 2)">
</div>

</div>
```

**Typescript** (only the related function)

```
getLeftDivHeight(id: string, divisionNumber: number): string {
height = document.GetElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect().height / 
divisionNumber;
return height + 'px';
}
```

Note that I am not looking for an HTML solution, but an Angular one, the code above is just an example to explain my problem.

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0):

You could return the whole style string, for example `height: 100px`, from the getLeftDivHeight method

`` getLeftDivHeight(id: string, divisionNumber: number): string {
    height = document.GetElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect().height / divisionNumber;
    return `height: ${height}px`;
} ``

or you could use the below syntax in the template

`[style.height.px]="getLeftDivHeight(parameters)"`

return only numerical height value from the method.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally manage to do it, using a directive.

I used ElementRef to access the HTML Object of my right div.

```
import {ElementRef,Renderer} from '@angular/core';
constructor(private el: ElementRef,public renderer: Renderer) {}
```

Then, I used Dom to access the left div height

```
this.el.nativeElement.parentElement.childElement[0].clientHeight;
```

Then I use `this.renderer.setElementStyle()` to apply style

I also learn that use offscrollheight to do the math is not a good idea !